# Программа не работает должным образом

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd

При выполнении кода:

```
import os 
os.system(r'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe cd C:\Users\clash\OneDrive\Рабочий стол')
os.system(r'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe attrib +h +s +r pas')
```

Происходит такое:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1016]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2019. Все права защищены.
```

При чем это не зависит от действия. Я пробовал с обычным открытием пайтон файла через консоль. Проблема одна и та же.

Comment: pas -- это файл на столе?

Comment: Какая программа и как должна работать? Что вы хотите получить в результате когда "программа" будет работать "должным образом"?

Comment: Да, pas это файл на столе. Программа заключается в том чтобы скрывать файл через команду attrib -h -s -r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы команды в командной строке выполнялись нужен ключ /C, т.е.

```
import os 
os.system(r'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C cd C:\Users\clash\OneDrive\Рабочий стол')
os.system(r'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C attrib +h +s +r pas')
```

---

**UPD.**
Если скрипт находится в другой директории, то обязательно указывайте полный путь к файлу:

```
os.system(r'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C attrib +h +s +r C:\Users\clash\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pas')
```

Comment: Возникла новая ошибка. Он не находит эту папку. Хотя она 100 процентов там есть. Не найден файл: pas

Comment: Скрипт в той же папке? Если нет, указывайте полный путь к файлу `attrib +h +s +r C:\Users\clash\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pas`

Comment: Добавил, но ничего не поменялось папку все равно не находит. Может оно выполняется отдельно? То есть сначала переход к файлу потом консоль закрывается. А потом снова открывается не в той директории и соответственно он не находит эту папку.

Comment: Замените `Рабочий стол` на `Desktop`. У меня все работает

Comment: Кстати, OneDrive? Вы хотите изменить атрибуты файла в облаке? А разрешения для этого у вас выставлены?

Comment: Там скорее всего проблема с кириллицей

Comment: А вторая команда разве предполагает, что текущий рабочий каталог станет таким, как указано при вызове предыдущей команды?

Comment: Нет, поэтому и добавил update

Comment: Как поменять название?. На Desktop я поменял в папке, но путь все равно показывается как  "Рабочий стол". Как выставить разрешение в OneDrive ? Тип если я пишу вручную эти команды, то  у меня работает.

Comment: И я думаю что если бы это были проблемы с разрешениями, то была бы другая ошибка

Comment: `C:\Users\Serg\Desktop>attrib +h +s +r C:\Users\Serg\Рабочий стол\pas
Ошибка в формате параметра -` не работает

`C:\Users\Serg\Desktop>attrib +h +s +r C:\Users\Serg\Desktop\pas` - работает. Особенности работы с OneDrive я не знаю

Comment: Даже со вторым вариантом выдает: "Ошибка в формате параметра -". Пробовал комментировать  первую строчку - не работает. Менял "Десктоп" на просто "Рабочий стол" - тоже не работает. Имя юзера тоже менял - безрезультатно.

Comment: Как поменять на английский весь диск C? И отключить OneDrive.

Comment: Смотрите тут [Как удалить OneDrive](https://bit.ly/32HdAP1)